# MVC3 FormCollection suddenly NULL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 app that is occasionally reporting a NullReferenceException. So far I have not been able to repro the problem. Below is an edited version of the function (to protect the innocent ;) and the corresponding stack output I get when the NullReferenceException is thrown.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(FormCollection collection)
{
    if (null == collection)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // other work occurs...


   // NOTE: no problem here accessing collection
   QcModel qcModel = new QcModel (Int32.Parse(collection["Id"]),  collection["Result"]);
   try
   {
       Process(qcModel); // Process() throws some kind of exception
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        TempData["ValidationError"] = ex.Message;

        // next line is the one that reports the NullReferenceException in stack, aka line 254
        return RedirectToAction("Order", new { Id = Int32.Parse(collection["Id"]), result = collection["Result"], reserved = 0 });
   }

    // additional work if we make it here...
}
```

Basically what I've deduced so far is that somehow by the time we get to the highlighted line in my catch{} the collection object is null. Now I can't prove that because I have not been able to repro this particular error, but I believe that is what's occuring because the exception generated in the catch bubbles up to a handler further up that sends the e-mail giving me this stack output:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException

Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack:    at MyWebsite.Controllers.MyController.DoSomething(FormCollection collection) in C:\MyWebsite\Controllers\MyController.cs:line 254
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Why not bind directly to `QcModel` in your action?

Comment: Without seeing Process, we don't know what's going on.  It looks like Process is clearing the collection.

Comment: I was planning on doing that in the interim, but that still leaves me perplexed as to what/how is currently going on.

Comment: Process() is not getting a reference to the "collection" object. It has it's own model object that simply gets a copy of two specific members within the "collection" object.

Comment: @Chris - What "other work" happens before Process?  Does any of it reference collection?  Another thing you can do is save those values as local variables to use later.

Comment: @MystereMan - good idea with the local variables, will give that a try.